# Timestamp to specific sheet in google sheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps, google-sheets-macros

```js
function onEdit() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  if (s.getName() == 'Wykaz poselski') {
  var rng = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('C7');
    rng.setValue(new Date());}
}
```

That code returns only hour in my spreadsheet, but I need full date (YYYY:MM:DD HH:MM:SS) Could you help me?

Answer (score 0):

**Adding DateTime to sheet on every edit**

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sh=e.range.getSheet();
  if (sh.getName()=='Wykaz poselski') {
    var ts=Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "yyyy:MM:dd HH:mm:ss")
    sh.getRange('C7').setValue(ts);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

To get the full date value you will need to use the [formatDate method of Utilities](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatdatedate,-timezone,-format). Here is the sample code with the right modification:

```js
function onEdit() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  if (s.getName() == 'Wykaz poselski') {
  var rng = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('C7');
    rng.setValue(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),  "GMT", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"));}
}
```

I hope this has helped you. Let me know if you need anything else or if you did not understood something. :)